# How to install Ubuntu desktop GUI in Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to install the Ubuntu desktop GUI through the command:
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
But the server sais:
E: Unable to locate package xubuntu-desktop
How can I solve it?

Comment: xubuntu-desktop  is in the Universe repository. Do you have a line in your sources.list that indicates teh universe for your installed version? https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/xubuntu-desktop

Comment: Ubuntu Server is meant to be a server... If you want a desktop use regular(X)ubuntu, and add the Apache/Nginx or whatever. If this is a VPS, the software sources could be pointing to the provider's repo without any desktop stuff and you'll have to add another repo. OTOH I manage my server through a GUI... on my local machine. If you have SSH access then you have SFTP and some file explorers/editors will use that natively (dolphin and kate...).